# Amazon SES Friendly From Header

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm having some trouble getting Amazon SES to display a friendly FROM header. The issue seems to be that SES is inserting an additional from header before mine.

I'm using Python boto, and sending a MIME message using the send_raw_email method.

```
to_str = 'Name <name@domain.com>'
from_str = 'Name2 <name2@domain.com>'
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Hello World'
msg['From'] = from_str
msg['To'] = to_str
msg.attach(MIMEText(em_plain, 'plain'))
msg.attach(MIMEText(em_html, 'html'))
ses_connection.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(), source=from_str, destinations=to_str)
```

What I get in the headers of the message that's delivered looks like this:

```
Subject: Hello World
Date: Thu, 9 Apr 2015 20:47:31 +0000
Message-ID: <blah-blah-blah@email.amazonses.com>
From: name2@domain.com
X-SES-Outgoing: 2015.blah.blah
Feedback-ID: 1.us-east-1.blah//blah=:AmazonSES

From: "Name2" <name2@domain.com>
To: "Name" <name@domain.com>
```

The result is that the user's mailbox does not display the friendly name. Plenty of info on the web says this is possible, but I can't get this working.

Looking into this further, if I omit the optional source parameter on the call to send_raw_email, the call fails with an error about a missing From header ... despite the fact that it has been set within the MimeMultipart object.

So, I think there are two issues - first, if I pass a friendly From header in the source parameter, it gets stripped down to just the email address. Second, the From that's in the MimeMultipart isn't recognized.

Comment: You are showing two different email addresses in the `From:` headers.  If that's really what you are doing, the answer should be self-evident.  Otherwise, please edit the question to align it more closely with what's happening here.

Comment: The same email address is used when setting the From header in the MimeMultipart object, and as a parameter to the send_raw_email method. Also updated the above with some new details.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Order of operations on the MIMEMultipart object matters.

You have to set the From header first, then the To, then the Subject.

If you do it in this order, then you can safely leave out the optional source and destination parameters on the send_raw_email call.

Would seem to be a limitation/issue with SES, as many other mail servers do not require the From header to come before the Subject.